# Is "UHT milk" called "boxed milk" or "long life milk" or "shelf stable milk"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I remembered some native speakers said "**you should not say a box of milk, but a carton of milk**".

However, in many Asian countries, they have milk in boxes that can be stored in room temperature for several months (**UTH milk**). They look like this (**picture 1**).

[image]

Also, in Asia, milk that can be **only** be stored in a fridge look like this (**picture 2**).

[image]

Is the box in the **picture 1** also called "**a carton**"?

Is "**UHT milk**" called "**boxed milk**" but not "**cartoned milk**"?

Comment: Are you asking about what to call that kind of milk in a box, or do you want to know the name of that type of packaging in general?

Comment: The answer is likely to be different if you're speaking to an American, an Australian, an Indian, etc. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Side note: I see examples from Vietnam, which is in the "Far East", not "Asia". Although Asia is the land mass, in BrE Asia usually refers to South Asia (India, Pakistan, Bangladesh) instead of East Asia (China, Thailand, Vietnam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UHT milk is also common outside Asia! UHT milk is called "long-life milk".

Both UHT milk and pasturised milk can be sold in cartons.  Both the containers above could be called cartons. The name of the packaging is separate from the type of milk that they contain.

You can have a "bottle of long-life milk", a "carton of pasturised milk".  I suspect that the first pack with a cuboid shape would be more convenient for storage (you can have a pile of such boxes) so it is more likely to contain UHT milk, but this is not a matter of English usage. The first carton is more "boxy" so it would not be strange to call the first one a box of milk.

Boxed milk is milk sold in a box (an not a bottle) Such milk is probably more likely to be UHT but doesn't have to be.